# How can I convert an address in Thailand from English to Thai?

Tags: thailand, language-barrier, english-language, thai-language

How can I convert an address in Thailand from English to Thai?

Motivations:

- give taxi drivers in Thailand the address in Thai
- send letters to an address in Thailand

E.g from:

> 25 Condo SPN Place, 7th Floor,
>
> Room 708,
>
> Soi Ladprao 80, Intersection 22 Ladprao Road,
>
> Wangthonglang, Subdistrict, Wangthonglang District
>
> Bangkok 10310

to:

> 25 คอนโด แส พี แอน เพลส ขั้น 7
>
> ห้อง 708
>
> ซอยลาดพร้าว 80 แยก 22
>
> ถ. ลากพร้าว แชวง วังทองหลาง เขค วังทองหลาง
>
> กรุงเทพ 10310

(Example taken from https://forum.thaivisa.com/topic/1019601-need-help-translating-thai-address-to-english-please/ ([mirror](https://archive.vn/cq02C/)), which I found when researching the question and according to https://redd.it/hhi4f9 is imperfect.)

I tried Google Translate but the translation was far from perfect.

Comment: Are these addresses that are likely to be listed on internet? If so, can you use a Thai version of the site to catch the address?

Comment: @Willeke thanks for the suggestion, good point, quite often this trick won't work though (e.g. because I got the address somewhere else such as text message, or that the website isn't available in both languages).

Comment: Google maps + changing you default language to Thai will get you pretty far.

Comment: That "Intersection 22 Ladprao Road" part doesn't really make sense, it's either soi 80 or soi 22 (and Thanon Ladprao isn't itself a soi of anything, is it?) Did you make that up or is that a real address?

Comment: @AndreKR I took the example from https://forum.thaivisa.com/topic/1019601-need-help-translating-thai-address-to-english-please/, which I found when researching the question.

Comment: Ah, that's Soi 80 Yaek 22 and then (on a new line) "Ladprao Road" again which is rather redundant, probably because there was a mandatory road field in a form.

Comment: Apart from the actual question, YSK that letters will arrive just fine if you write the address in English and for taxi drivers it would be better to *say* the address (maybe make a recording on your phone).

Answer (score 30):

If you're looking for a fully automated way, **you can't**. Thai romanization is nonstandard and lossy, and Thai script has many redundant letters, so you can't tell if a "kh" is supposed to be ข *kho khai* or ค *kho khwai*, much less get the vital tone markings right.

However!  If you punch in a romanized Thai address into **Google Maps** (in the mobile app), and it can work it out, it will offer you the Thai script version as well, complete with a handy speaker button for reading it out loud:

[image]

That said, while this works well for major landmarks, for some addresses like your example it doesn't recognize the building itself.  It'll still get you in the vicinity though.  You will also often need to manually strip all extra info like floor/unit so it doesn't mistakenly latch onto those.

Comment: As well echoing that advice, I'll add another possible complication which is that sometimes the English name is a translation rather than transliteration of the Thai name or vice versa.  And yet another complication is that the name occasionally comes from another language.  You need some look up procedure.

Comment: The funny-looking `QG2R+92` thingy is a [unique identifier for that address](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/7047426). If you look this code up in advance, it makes it a lot more likely that you'll be able to find what you want later.

Answer (score 8):

Here's what I do:

- Keep the building name in latin characters
- Learn to write "floor", "room", "house" and "soi"
- Translate the Thanon using Wikipedia or Google Maps (for smaller streets)
- Translate the Tambon, Amphoe and Changwat using Wikipedia

Comment: Thanks for sharing the translation strategy. That sounds like fully / almost automatable :)

Answer (score 4):

One solution from [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Thailand/comments/hhi4f9/how_can_i_convert_an_address_in_thailand_from/fwa71j5/) ([mirror](https://archive.vn/ekkkb)) posted by users [cranialmatters](https://www.reddit.com/user/cranialmatters) and [bingy_bongy_bangy](https://www.reddit.com/user/bingy_bongy_bangy), also based on Google Maps:

> If you find the address on google maps in English, then change the language to Thai (to do this, paste `?hl=th` onto the end of the URL) while you have the address pinned you may then get the Thai address.

Example with the address "847 Phetchaburi Rd, Thanon Phaya Thai, Ratchathewi, Bangkok 10400":

- English: https://www.google.com/maps/place/847+Phetchaburi+Rd,+Khwaeng+Thanon+Phaya+Thai,+Khet+Ratchathewi,+Krung+Thep+Maha+Nakhon+10400/@13.7513251,100.5380502,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x30e29ecf52b8efe7:0xaf2ab112d2106745!8m2!3d13.7513251!4d100.5402389 ([mirror](https://archive.vn/z3Yh1))
- Thai: https://www.google.com/maps/place/847+Phetchaburi+Rd,+Khwaeng+Thanon+Phaya+Thai,+Khet+Ratchathewi,+Krung+Thep+Maha+Nakhon+10400/@13.7513251,100.5380502,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x30e29ecf52b8efe7:0xaf2ab112d2106745!8m2!3d13.7513251!4d100.5402389?hl=th ([mirror](https://archive.vn/btiTm)), which gives "847 ถนน เพชรบุรี, แขวง ถนนพญาไท เขตราชเทวี, กรุงเทพมหานคร 10400"

[image][image]

Comment: @Willeke the other answer doesn't mention we can switch the Google maps language setting. They use a different trick.